# Domain expires using parse-whois and node-whois

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get the value of the domain expiration attribute but at the moment I still can't, does anyone have any idea how can I do this?

```
    var result =
[
    {
      attribute: '%  2021-05-24T10:05:36-03:00 - IP',
      value: '177.222.158.61'
    },
    { attribute: 'domain', value: 'compasso.com.br' },
    { attribute: 'owner', value: 'COMPASSO INFORM�TICA S.A.' },
    { attribute: 'ownerid', value: '' },
    { attribute: 'responsible', value: '' },
    { attribute: 'country', value: 'BR' },
    { attribute: 'owner-c', value: 'CHG73' },
    { attribute: 'tech-c', value: 'RRU3' },
    {
      attribute: 'nserver',
      value: ''
    },
    { attribute: 'nsstat', value: '20210524 AA' },
    { attribute: 'nslastaa', value: '20210524' },
    { attribute: 'nserver', value: 'pdns03.domaincontrol.com' },
    { attribute: 'nsstat', value: '20210524 AA' },
    { attribute: 'nslastaa', value: '20210524' },
    { attribute: 'nserver', value: 'pdns04.domaincontrol.com' },
    { attribute: 'nsstat', value: '20210524 AA' },
    { attribute: 'nslastaa', value: '20210524' },
    { attribute: 'created', value: '19960613 #9589' },
    { attribute: 'changed', value: '20200623' },
    { attribute: 'expires', value: '20250613' },
  ]

  console.log("expires value");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = [
  {
    attribute: '%  2021-05-24T10:05:36-03:00 - IP',
    value: '177.222.158.61',
  },
  { attribute: 'domain', value: 'compasso.com.br' },
  { attribute: 'owner', value: 'COMPASSO INFORM�TICA S.A.' },
  { attribute: 'ownerid', value: '' },
  { attribute: 'responsible', value: '' },
  { attribute: 'country', value: 'BR' },
  { attribute: 'owner-c', value: 'CHG73' },
  { attribute: 'tech-c', value: 'RRU3' },
  {
    attribute: 'nserver',
    value: '',
  },
  { attribute: 'nsstat', value: '20210524 AA' },
  { attribute: 'nslastaa', value: '20210524' },
  { attribute: 'nserver', value: 'pdns03.domaincontrol.com' },
  { attribute: 'nsstat', value: '20210524 AA' },
  { attribute: 'nslastaa', value: '20210524' },
  { attribute: 'nserver', value: 'pdns04.domaincontrol.com' },
  { attribute: 'nsstat', value: '20210524 AA' },
  { attribute: 'nslastaa', value: '20210524' },
  { attribute: 'created', value: '19960613 #9589' },
  { attribute: 'changed', value: '20200623' },
  { attribute: 'expires', value: '20250613' },
];

const expires = result.filter((one) => one.attribute === 'expires').pop();
const at = expires.value;

console.log(at);
```

You can learn more about working with arrays at https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-array-of-objects-tutorial-how-to-create-update-and-loop-through-objects-using-js-array-methods/.

Essentially, all we're doing here is looping through an array and stopping when the `attribute` = 'expires'.

I use the `.filter()` to obtain the object containing `attribute` = 'expires' and then use .pop() (if you expect multiple `expires` attributes, use a different approach).

And finally I'll obtain the value and assign that to `at`. The array has been reduced from many objects into one, making it far easier to work with.